# Is it possible to redirect to new page after send file method

Tags: ruby

Ruby method send_file itself redirects to file to server.
But I want to customize that redirection and need to redirect to another page.

Comment: So you don't want to send the contents of the file?

Comment: I want to send the contents of file but also want to redirect to new page to refresh the contents of the page.

Comment: I have download link, on click of link modal window is opened, there added option to send file to server, but while sending the file to server, also want to close the modal window using ajax and refresh the contents of the page

Answer (score 1):

The way a redirection of this type is performed is using the `Location` header in the HTTP response. You cannot return content and a redirect in the same response.

What you can do, however, is link to a page that performs the download after a short amount of time, and then redirects.

Have a look at the HTML [Meta Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) feature.