# Ruby Sinatra: redirect page not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

The problem lies in the following code ("routes.rb").

```
  post 'download_csr' do
    file_name = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/cert.csr'
    File.open(file_name, 'w') do |f|
      f.write params[:csr]
    end
    send_file file_name, :disposition => 'attachment'
    erb :load_certificate, :locals => { :csr => 'cert.csr' }
  end
```

The flow is this: the user clicks a button on a form, then a file is written and downloaded to local system, then it goes to another page (i.e., "load_certificate.erb").

However, what really happens is that after the file is downloaded, it doesn't go to the next page. But if I comment out "send_file", it will go to the next page. So how to address this? Thanks a lot!

One more thing: it would be good to make sure the file is actually downloaded before going to the next page (because when send_file pops out a window, the user can choose "cancel"). Some time-out mechanism may not work here.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859579/is-it-possible-to-redirect-to-new-page-after-send-file-method

Answer (score 0):

@Soup's link is a good one to read. With regard to Sinatra, [`send_file` calls `halt`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L370), which ends the request (in this case by sending the status and the file). [Nothing will be processed after a `halt`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting).